# First steps with SQLite and C

Tags: c, sqlite, include

i'm trying to use SQLite in C. I downloaded the precompiled Binaries for Windows from the SQLite-Homepage. I extracted them and added sqlite to my environment path var. Using the command line, everything works.
Now i trying to use sqlite in a simply C-Code. Many Tutorials showed me to beginn with:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
```

But my Compiler can't find the the file. The same result, trying with:

```
#include "C:/sqlite/sqlite3.h"
```

I'm new at C but don't i need a Header-File (*.h) for the #include command? Because the downloaded sqlite package only consist of: sqlite3.def, sqlite3.dll, sqlite3.exe (shell).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried downloading the source from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html ?

Answer (score 0):

To use SQLite, download the source (the amalgamation), and include `sqlite3.c` in your project, together with your other source files.
(The `sqlite3.h` file should be in the same directory.)

Comment: Thank you, i downloaded now the source files. Is it enough to put the sqlite3.h in the folder of my c projekt? And then including it with #include "sqlite.h" ? Because when doing this, i'm getting an error lnk2019 from my compiler!

Comment: Its on german but translated it means something like: "reference unresolved external symbol"

Comment: Do i have to link the files or something like that?

Comment: Thank you for keeping the name of the symbol a secret. And yes, you have to link with the .obj file that you compiled from the `sqlite3.c` file (just compile the `sqlite3.c` file together with your other `.c` file(s)).

Comment: Sorry for that. .....'the unsresovled external symbol "_sqlite3_version" in Function "_sqlite3_libversion" '